How to clear Chrome browsing history on restart?
Is there a way to configure Chrome to clear browsing history whenever it restarts?
I know that I can do this manually by going to the clear browsing data section on settings. But I want the browser to completely remove any browsing history on every restart.

Here is a wrapper shell script mychrome.sh to launch chrome:
#!/bin/bash
rm $HOME/.config/google-chrome/Default/History*
exec google-chrome "$@"

Or, Windows batch script mychrome.bat:
@echo off
del "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History"
start google-chrome

Add shortcut entry to the shell script in the start menu or on the desktop.

You can also do it by setting the policy SavingBrowserHistoryDisabled
to true. This is done differently in each OS.
In Windows you do it via registry, as described in the above link. Registry value Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\SavingBrowserHistoryDisabled = 0x00000001
In Linux you can set it via a json file placed under one of the following directories (depending on the case):

/etc/chromium-browser/policies/managed/
/etc/chromium/policies/managed/
/etc/opt/chromium/policies/managed/

There is also an answer on Ask Ubuntu that describes paths in case of snap, though in my case, even with snap installation the first one of the above dirs worked.
Inside any of the above create a json file e.g. custom_policy.json with the content:
{
  "SavingBrowserHistoryDisabled": true
}


And I believe the directory and file should not be writable after the edit.
After the change, check chrome://policy/ page to verify that the policy was correctly set.
Note: The setting may not remove the existing history, so you can remove this manually, the first time, from the settings.
